# Select element in drag event using arrow functions in v6

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the drag event to move an element. In order to move the element I must select it first. I do this within arrow functions like so:

```
const drag = d3.drag()
 .on('start', (e, d) => this.dragstarted(e, d))
 .on('drag', (e, d) => this.dragged(e, d))
 .on('end', (e, d) => this.dragended(e, d))
```

I wish to select the current element

```
  dragged(event:any, d:any) {
   console.log(d3.select(event.currentTarget))
  }
```

This does not work. It seems to only work if I use a non arrow function:

```
const _this = this;
...
.on('drag', function (e, d) { _this.dragged(e, d, this) })
...
dragged(event:any, d:any, el:any) {
   console.log(d3.select(el))
}
```

Version 5 passed the nodes and index of the element that could be used for selection:

```
dragged(d, i, nodes) {
    d3.select(nodes[i])
}
```

Is there a way to select the svg element within the arrow function to get a handle on the item within the drag event in V6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the D3 drag handlers, `this` is the same as `event.sourceEvent.target`, so:

```
.on('drag', function(e, d) { onDrag(this, d); })
```

will work the same as:

```
.on('drag', (e, d) => onDrag(e.sourceEvent.target, d))
```

Please note that the code is valid for **V6** / **V7**. For **V5** or earlier, use `d3.event.sourceEvent.target`

Answer (score 1):

I tried Michael's answer, but `e.sourceEvent.target` not work with **V6/V7**. The code that work for me in **V6/V7** is `(event) => {return event.currentTarget;}`. Perhaps we should use old style anonymous function `function(){return this;}` when dealing with `this`.